# What is below type of function definition/declaration called?

Tags: c

e.g.

```
void foo(var1, var2, var3)
  int var1,var3;
  char var2;
{
  ----
}
```

This is not supported in VS2013, but works in gcc4.8.
Does this type of function definition has any name?

Comment: K&R style declaration. It was replaced by ANSI style declaration.

Comment: It's how functions was defined in C a very long time ago. If you have seen it in a book, then throw it away and find something modern (check e.g. [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)#K.26R_C

Comment: @MohitJain: ... A long time ago, in a standard's commitee session far, far away...

Comment: Thank you all for the answers.